# how to avoid overwrite file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, file, nsurlconnection

i am using NSURLConnection to download file from server and storing it locally as follows

```
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
    didReceiveData:(NSData *)data  
{  
   [webData appendData:data];  
   paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES);  

   self.documentsDir = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NewResult.zip" ];  

   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:documentsDir contents:nil attributes:nil];  
   NSFileHandle *file1 = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath: documentsDir];  
   [file1 writeData: webData];  

   [file1 closeFile];  
}
```

this is working but overwrite old file every time 
how to avoid this over writing I know this is possible with NSURLDownload but here i am not using NSURLDownload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]){
    NSLog(@"File not exists at path %@", path);
    }else{
    NSLog(@"File exists at path:%@", path);
}
```

Comment: this will only shows file already exists or not but i want to create new file every time like NewResult1,NewResult2,NewResult3,...an so on

Comment: Get a counter and create your own file paths